# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found by bundle in karaf

Tags: java, osgi, karaf

I have a bundle which is using mySQL.jdbc.driver , I have given the dependency in pom file,import-packages and copied mysql connector in lib, deploy folder , installed mysql driver using install wrap:mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.17,
i mean I did all possible as per me,
but still I am getting error message as under, FYI I am using  karaf-4.0.0.M2, please help its road block for me,

```
errorMessage = JDBC driver name is missing or not valid, cause = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found by portframeworkservice [this is my bundle name]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found by portframeworkservice [145]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1556)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1993)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code you use to initialize the mysql driver?

Answer (score 3):

Database drivers in OSGi are always a bit difficult as the most common approach outside OSGi using DriverManager is not really suitable for OSGi.

The best approach in OSGi is to use a DataSourceFactory which is standardized by the OSGi alliance. Some database drivers already offer this. For others pax-jdbc provides an adapter. For mysql the second case applies.

So my advice is to use pax-jdbc like this:

```
feature:repo-add pax-jdbc 0.6.0
feature:install pax-jdbc-mysql
```

If you then do

```
karaf@root()> service:list DataSourceFactory
[org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory]
-----------------------------------------
 osgi.jdbc.driver.class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = mysql
 service.bundleid = 52
 service.id = 110
 service.scope = singleton
```

So the feature offers you a ready to use DataSourceFactory. You can bind it as an OSGi service and create a DataSource from it.
To make it even more convenient you can also use [pax-jdbc-config](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Create+DataSource+from+config) and [pax-jdbc-pool](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Pooling+and+XA+support+for+DataSourceFactory) to create a ready to use pooled DataSource as a service.

I have a complete [tutorial for accessing databases in OSGi](http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/LYBk) that shows this approach.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like these features are maintained, the pax-jdbc-myql project, for example, is using a mysql driver last updated 3 years ago https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/commit/cb9a0db80c75b4b909b61f51120cf2547b103417 .

Comment: pax-jdbc supports a big number of databases. People usually update a driver when they need a new version for their own project. If you create a PR for a new mysql version I can help you to get it into the code.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider: I created a datasource as per your description and put a <reference/> to this DS in the blueprint.xml of my camel project. However, when starting Karaf the blueprint fails to initialize because the DS is not availabe at the time of blueprint-initialization. If I wait for Karaf to start I can deploy the project without problems, but when I try to auto-boot my bundle during startup it always fails with said exception. Would you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: It is completely normal that the DataSource might not be present when you blueprint context starts up. Blueprint should wait for the DataSource to show up and then continue starting your blueprint. Can you show your project on github?